# Trouble with using variables

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently working on a script to do large amounts of copy-and-pasting in a CSV. (We're doing a product import file for Magento)

```
def select_cell(m):
    return 'row.'+ m

def mageimport(f,x):    #let x = table_size  let y = color or wood_stain
    sku_copy = [row.sku for index, row in f.iterrows() if type(select_cell(x)) != float]
    option1 = [x for index, row in f.iterrows() if type(select_cell(x)) != float]
    option2 = [select_cell(x) for index, row in f.iterrows() if type(select_cell(x)) != float]

    df = {}
    df = {'_super_products_sku':sku_copy, '_super_attribute_code':option1, '_super_attribute_option':option2}
    return df
```

If I use the code exactly as above, any value I put in for x returns a string instead of a cell from my dataframe. I know the problem comes from the `select_cell()` function but I don't know how to get around it.

If I replace `select_cell()` with `row.table_size`, the info comes out right. I can do that as a last resort, but I'd prefer making this function work.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is `x` an integer == the length of the table, or is it the string `"table_size"`, or something else?

Comment: @HughBothwell f is what I've named the dataframe and x is supposed to be any one of the column names. So, x.table_size gives me the column that has product sizes. I'd like to apply it to other columns as well: f.colors, f.wood_stain, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a string in `select_cell`. It should always return `str` as the `type()`.

Try using (I don't know what row is, but I assume it is either a module/class or a globally available object). I'm going to create a simple one here.

```
class row:
    a = 10
    b = 20

def select_cell(m):
    if hasattr(row, m):
        return getattr(row, m)
    return None

assert select_cell('a') == 10
assert select_cell('b') == 20
assert select_cell('c') is None
```

Comment: The various mentnions of 'row.' are for selecting specific columns from the dataframe, which I've named f. If I type 'row.table_size' or 'row.color' instead of using select_cell(), it gives me the value I expect in my option2 list. Right now it gives me [ row.table_size, row.table_size, row.table_size, row.table_size]